# Scale Invariant Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

I am looking for a reference to the concept of Scale Invariant SVD which is mentioned in the "variations and generalisations" section of the Wikipedia article for SVD:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Variations_and_generalizations

There is a single link mentioned in the footnotes (reference note 27), but it is not working. In particular, I want a reference to how exactly one goes about calculating the scale invariant singular values, perhaps with some examples.

Also, it would be helpful if I could get other such variations and/or generalisations of SVD